# Prevent org-mode code block background color from bleeding through when collapsed?

Tags: org-mode

I'm applying a background color to code blocks in org-mode, as shown in this line from my colortheme:

```
'(org-block ((t (:background "#F5F5F5" :family "Source Code Pro" :height 140))))
```

[image: expanded item with code block]

When I collapse an item that contains a code block, the code block's background color extends from the end of the item's heading to the edge of the window, which I did not expect -- I expected collapsing the item would hide any evidence of the contained code-block.

[image: collapsed item with code block]

Is there any way to prevent the code block background from "bleeding through" like this?

Answer (score 1):

I found that adding a blank line past the source block prevents the bleeding.

Comment: Confirmed. But is this a bug or by design? It seems header formatting should be independent of its collapse/expand state (except for the presence of ellipses to indicate collapsed content.)

Comment: Correction: This issue appears be unique to specific themes. For example, leuven theme does not exhibit the above behavior.

Comment: Has this issue been resolved? I am still observing it on my system

Answer (score 0):

You found a known bug tracked here:

https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=52587