# Does anybody know what Emacs theme this is?

Tags: themes

What is the Emacs theme that is used in this screenshot?
[image: screenshot]

I stumbled upon it in the question [Prevent org-mode code block background color from bleeding through when collapsed?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26716/prevent-org-mode-code-block-background-color-from-bleeding-through-when-collapse).

Comment: A better question might be, *"How can I find out what theme(s) are currently used"*.

Comment: It is not, but its clean minimalist style reminds me of [nano-theme](https://github.com/rougier/nano-theme). Both look great!